# Putting SQL Server data into variable?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to put data from a SQL server table into a variable, but I keep getting errors on this line.

```
SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

The error type is below

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

And the code leading into the error. It is a trusted database BTW.

```
int staff_No;            
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=OWNER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Staff_Manager;Integrated Security=SSPI;");            
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT Staff_No FROM Staff_Data_TBL WHERE Staff_No = 1001";
sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlCmd.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();            
SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
dataReader.Read();
staff_No = dataReader.GetInt32(0);
Console.WriteLine(staff_No);
conn.Close();
```

And what the application is using.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
```

I don't know what else I can do to get this to work?

Comment: You need to look at the `.InnerException` of your exception you're getting for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ELewis is correct and this will also help you

```
 while (dataReader.Read())
  {
     //The 0 stands for "the 0'th column", so the first column of the result.
     var myString = dataReader.GetString(0); 
  }
```

OR

```
string myString = dataReader["ColumnOneName"].ToString();
```

OR

```
string myString = dataReader[0].ToString();
```

Comment: thanks, I changed the variable to a string and everything works now. But, what is the purpose of while loop?

Comment: when we have a multiple row data in datareader at that time you have to access value one by one

Comment: what I thought. Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

This line is incorrect:

```
sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

That should be set to

```
sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
```

Comment: @E Lewis, thanks ,now everything is working correctly. Why would my line of code not work, I thought I was dealing with a stored value?

Comment: The CommandText you have listed is not a stored procedure but is actual sql text.  You could create a stored procedure in your database called something like "GetStaffNo" that would execute the code you currently have as your CommandText.  You would then set the CommandType to StoredProcedure like you have and then the CommandText would be set to "GetStaffNo".

Comment: @E Lewis. Thanks again for the explanation.